# MySQL 2nd WHERE clause gives slow (Unending) result

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join, where-clause

I have a query which joins 3 tables (one inner join, one left join).
I need 2 WHERE conditions.
If I use either condition by itself, the search is quick.  If I use both, the search will not complete.
I don't think I can add the search clause directly to the join as I don't want to exclude results where the search term is not present in that join.

```
SELECT job_entry.Job_Number,
job_entry.subject_ref,
contacts_library.company
FROM job_entry 
LEFT JOIN multi_part_wind_instructions 
ON job_entry.Job_Number = multi_part_wind_instructions.job_number
INNER JOIN contacts_library 
ON job_entry.ContactID = contacts_library.ContactID
WHERE
company LIKE '%example%' 
OR
multi_part_wind_instructions.address LIKE '%example%' 
LIMIT 10
```

---

Explain Results query with both WHERE conditions:

```
+----+-------------+------------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | job_entry | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16234 | Using where | 
| 1 | SIMPLE | contacts_library | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | euroims.job_entry.ContactID | 1 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | multi_part_wind_instructions | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 39447 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+------------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Explain results from single WHERE condition (quick):

```
+----+-------------+------------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | job_entry | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16234 | Using where | 
| 1 | SIMPLE | contacts_library | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | euroims.job_entry.ContactID | 1 | Using index condition; Using where | 
| 1 | SIMPLE | multi_part_wind_instructions | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 39447 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) | 
+----+-------------+------------------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Add the `explain` output (for your fast single and your slow combined queries). It feels like you are missing an index on `job_number`.

Comment: Add an index for `multi_part_wind_instructions(job_number)`. For your `like`, you cannot use indexes, but this should help with the `join`. On the other hand, 40k rows are not enough to be so slow to not end.